# React Material UI onFocusOut

Tags: reactjs, uitextfield, material-ui

I currently use

```
<TextField onChange={e => this.change(e, items)}
```

This gets fired at every single letter I put into the TextField, consequently, text I type gets filled in slow motion. I was thinking it'd be better if this request goes out once the user types everything and focuses away. What kind of event I can use in this scenario with React & Material UI TextField ?

Comment: interesting. It should not be happening in slow motion. React should update even single character state change inputs very fluidly

Comment: It does, but I have an API call behind the scene too...

Comment: Or perhaps, I can await the API call? how ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having a debounced version of your function is useful when any DOM event is attached. It reduces the number of calls to this function to the bare minimum and thereby improve the performance.

So, you can do this:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.onChangeDebounce = _.debounce(e => this.change(e, items), 300);
}

render() {
    ...
    onChange={e => this.onChangeDebounce(e)}
    ...
}
```

In this case, I am passing to `debounce` only two parameters:

1. The function to be rate-limited
2. The rate limit in milliseconds, ie., the time to wait before the function is fired.

**Or** you can use onBlur event, that is available for any DOM element. The onBlur event happens whenever an input loses focus on. In other words: when you remove your cursor from within the input, it loses "focus", or becomes "blurry".

The caveat is that it doesn't have an associated event, so, to reach what you want, you can update the state with the field value and on onBlur, retrieve this value from state.

Here you have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aldomonteiro/b0395gqk/9/) doing this.

Comment: What does this debounce do? Only time intervals in this code will be sent to the function?? So from the user starts typing every 300 miliseconds function will be run? Can you update me on it?.. My thought was, once user types all letters and focuses out of the input area. Clicking tab button will do it, clicking anywhere outside of the box will do it..Then we know user is done typing..

Comment: That's it, debounce postpone the code execution, so, it runs only after time interval. I suggested that because it is a common practice when you are tunning javascript applications and, compared to your idea, it has a pro: if the user type something and stop, you can still run your code and, when he lands in another field, your process will be done. However, if you think this does not fit into your solution, I am gonna suggest onBlur event. I am gonna update my answer.

Answer (score 5):

After one and a half year, here is a contemporary approach mostly for functional components:

- Keep the value of the field as a React `state`.
- Set it `onChange`
- Persist (or do whatever expensive process) `onBlur`

So, a component containing this text field would, in a way, look like similar to this:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core'

const MyFunctionalComponent = () => {

  const [textFieldValue, setTextFieldValue] = useState('') 
  // ...

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {/** ...  */}
      <TextField
        value={textFieldValue}
        onChange={(e) => setTextFieldValue(e.target.value)}
        onBlur={() => {
          console.log(`I am blurred and ready to process ${textFieldValue}`)
        }}
      />
      {/** ... */}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```